# can rsync --link-dest tell me if if had to copy any files at all?

Tags: rsync, backup

I'm working on scripts to backup things using --link_dest to provide multiple directory versions. Is there anything rsync can tell me about if it had to copy any new or changed files at all? If there are no changes since the previous backup, I'd like to remove the new backup I just made. I'm sure I could examine the directories with some script to determine this, but it would be faster if rsync could just tell me since it certainly knows if it had to transfer a file over rather than making a link.

Comment: Similar? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497990/how-to-know-if-rsync-did-not-change-any-files

Comment: The --stats info almost works, but since it is copying things to an empty directory, it has no way to report anything that was deleted. I'd have to save the status from the last backup and compare the count of files and directories to see if deletions happened. Maybe I'll do that someday, but I just won't bother with this today.